# Why does the saved image not have the same data as the modified before saving?

Tags: c#, image

What I want to do:
Load an image, store a message in the first bits of the message, save the image, load the saved image, get the message and output it to the console.

Program.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

if (!RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) {
    Console.WriteLine("only windows is supported");
    return;
}

// logging the first 100 bytes of a byte array
static string GetMessage(byte[] imageBytes) {
    byte[] bt = new byte[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++) {
        bt[i] = imageBytes[i];
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bt);
}

// loading an image and saving another with a message in it
{
    string filename = "image.jpg";
    ImageByter imgb = new(filename);

    string messageStr = File.ReadAllText("message.txt");
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageStr);
    BitArray messageBits = new BitArray(messageBytes);

    imgb.Bits = ProcessImage(imgb.Bits, messageBits);

    Console.WriteLine(GetMessage(imgb.Bytes));

    imgb.SaveFile("message_image.jpg");

    static BitArray ProcessImage(BitArray imageBits, BitArray messageBits) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messageBits.Count; i++) {
            imageBits.Set(i, messageBits.Get(i));
        }
        return imageBits;
    }
}

// loading the image with the message
{
    string filename = "message_image.jpg";
    ImageByter imgb = new(filename);

    Console.WriteLine(GetMessage(imgb.Bytes));
}
```

ImageByter.cs:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections;

[System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public class ImageByter {
    private byte[] _bytes = new byte[0];

    public byte[] Bytes {
        get {
            return _bytes;
        }
        set {
            _bytes = value;
            _bits = new BitArray(value);
        }
    }

    private BitArray _bits;

    public BitArray Bits {
        get {
            return _bits;
        }
        set {
            _bits = value;
            _bytes = BitArrayToByteArray(value);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap inputImage;
    private IntPtr pointeur;
    private BitmapData bmpData;

    public ImageByter(string fileName) {
        FileStream bmpstream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        inputImage = new Bitmap(bmpstream);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, inputImage.Width, inputImage.Height);
        bmpData = inputImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, inputImage.PixelFormat);
        pointeur = bmpData.Scan0;
        int bytesLength = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmpData.Height;
        
        _bytes = new byte[bytesLength];

        Marshal.Copy(pointeur, _bytes, 0, bytesLength);

        _bits = new BitArray(_bytes);
    }

    public void SaveFile(string outputFileName) {
        if (inputImage == null || bmpData == null)
            return;

        Marshal.Copy(_bytes, 0, pointeur, _bytes.Length);

        inputImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        inputImage.Save(outputFileName);
    }

    static byte[] BitArrayToByteArray(BitArray bits) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bits.Count / 8];
        bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

The constructor of ImageByter is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852275/c-sharp-modify-a-byte-array-and-convert-to-image#:%7E:text=OpenFileDialog%20openFileDialog%20%3D%20new%20OpenFileDialog()%3B%0AopenFileDialog,spotImage.UnlockBits(bmpData)%3B%0A%0ApictureBox2.Image%20%3D%20spotImage%3B).
I initially thought it would be simpler to load an image, modify the bytes, and then save it. But with the simple solution I got all the bytes in the header of the image also.

The output I get when the message is aabbccdd is this:
From the modified image before saving it:

aabbccddK$YL%ZM%ZM%ZM%ZM UH"WJ$YL$YL#XK#XK$YL%[N%[N#[N$\O$\O$\O%]P%]P%]P%]P&^Q&^Q&^Q&^Q%]P$\O%[N%ZM'

From the loaded modified image:

7l_4i/dW)^Q&[N%ZM%ZM%ZM UH"WJ$YL$YL#XK#XK$YL%[N%[N#[N$\O$\O$\O%]P%]P%]P%]P&^Q&^Q&^Q&^Q%]P$\O%[N%ZM'

As you can see it is mostly the same except in the beginning.

Comment: An image has an ascii header which contains the type of image (may include resolution).  You are modifying the header.  I would open the files with notepad and compare headers to get better understanding of the issue.  You are using a FileStream and have to advance the stream past the header before you start to modify.

Comment: @jdweng As far as I can tell, he is modifying the data at `bmpData.Scan0`, this is the raw pixeldata, and does not include any header. The header should be parsed and recreated by the bitmap. But I'm wondering why not just do `Marshal.Copy(messageBytes, 0, bmpData.Scan0, 0, messageBytes.Length)`. Messing around with bitarrays just seem add complexity and increase the risk for something failing.

Comment: You cannot change the image data, save the image as a jpeg and expect the data to be exactly the same. Jpeg is a lossy compression, so you cannot expect the exact same bytes. Use .png or .bmp instead when saving.

Comment: @JonasH : The why is the ascii header getting modified?

Comment: @jdweng The `ImageByter` is used to print the data, and this extracts the pixel-data. I see nothing that uses the header, or uses the raw file stream for anything except loading/saving a bitmap. And while jpeg files have a header, it is not really anything 'ascii' about it. It starts with a magic value followed by various binary encoded segments for various types of data.

Comment: All image file will have an optional header and at the end a character indicating where the binary image actually starts.  The header usually contains a combination of ascii and non ascii characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JonasH mentioned in the comments. I can't be using jpeg format if I want the data to be safe.
I changed it to png and now it works. Thank you Jonas!